# How to Install Istio CRDs in Remote Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio

To avoid any XY problem, I'm sharing the full story.
I'd like to deploy a multi-cluster setup of Istio; specifically Primary-Remote (single mesh, single network) setup. Following [this](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/primary-remote/) guide after a lot of troubleshooting, finally I managed to deploy both clusters with the required resources and tested and everything working just fine.
Now the issue is that when I try to deploy a VirtualService to the remote cluster, K8S complains that the it doesn't know VirtualService (for obvious reason that the Istio CRDs are not installed in the remote cluster).
Now my questions are:

1. Shouldn't we also install the CRDs in the remote cluster? Or am I missing something?
2. If yes, then how can install only CRDs using `istioctl`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install the Istio CRDs in the remote cluster to enable the use of Istio resources such as VirtualService in a remote Kubernetes cluster.

Use this command to install CRDs using istioctl

```
istioctl install --set profile=remote -y --set components.crdInstallation.enabled=true
```

See this [document](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/) to know more about using istioctl

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it seems installing the CRDs alone won’t be enough. How would Istio knows about those resources in the remote cluster. That means another Istio is needed in the remote cluster, makes it a multi-primary setup.

Comment: You need to install the Istio control plane in both the primary and remote clusters to use Istio's multi-cluster features. The Istio control plane includes the Istio CRDs, so you don't need to install them separately in the primary cluster.